# nsepy returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, nsepy

nsepy get_history is returning an empty dataframe. What could be the reason for this?
I am using `version 0.7(latest version)`

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
from nsepy import *
end_day = date.today()
start_day = end_day - timedelta(2)
stock_price_df = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start= date.today() - timedelta(2), end= date.today())
```

Comment: did you got the solution? iam also facing same isse
tried uninstaling nsepy and reinstalled by still didnt worked

Comment: NSE block the IP if they notice bulk data retrieval from that IP.

Comment: but it was not that much data
only around 20 requests during my developement phase

Comment: That might be sufficient enough to be blocked :)  You can try few days later they re-enable the IP back

Comment: ok, i have implemetned it with yahoo finance, till now no issues